# Writing a for loop in a Pine script

Tags: for-loop, pine-script

I am new to programming.

I wish to write a code in pine script to add range (high-low) for x number of bars back.

Below is part of the code:

```
//@version=3
study(title="Vola", overlay = false)
xnum= input(20)

RangeA= for i = 1 to xnum 
    val_x=high[i]-low[i]
    adding=adding+val_x



plot(RangeA, color=red, linewidth=2)

error---------------------------------
line 7: Undeclared identifier `adding`;
line 11: Undeclared identifier `RangeA`
```

Comment: I wonder if you problem is not too clear. I assume the code block is in fact two parts: some code and the error. It may be worth splitting it up so that this is clearer.

Comment: I don't know Pine, but maybe you need to declare those variables before using them?

Answer (score -1):

No need for a `for` loop to do this in Pine. It will be much faster to use the built-in [`highest()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_highest) and [`lowest()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_lowest) functions. The debugging plots in here won't show in the indicator's pane, but you can see them in the indicator's values or in the Data Window (3rd icon from the top right of your chart):

```
//@version=4
study(title="Vola", overlay = false)
xnum= input(20)
hi = highest(xnum)
lo = lowest(xnum)
range = hi - lo
plot(range, "Range")
// Debugging plots.
plotchar(range, "range", "", location.top)
plotchar(hi, "hi", "", location.top, color.green)
plotchar(lo, "lo", "", location.top, color.red)
```

Comment: Thanks.How can I add the range of all 20 bars together ie. high minus low of bar 1 plus high minus low of bar2 ..etc

Comment: @NewBee I think you need `RangeA= sum(high - low, xnum)` - it'll get sum of `high-low` in last last `xnum` (which is 20) bars

Comment: Thanks Michel_T it works. To LucF: I bookmarked pinecoders.com